# Network issues, resolving host

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, dns, tcp

My network connection randomly drops for a 5 minutes or so when I'm online. It always happens when I boot up my computer.  I can tell because it says:`resolving host` in Chrome and I can't ping any websites. This lasts for at least 5 minutes. All other devices on the network have no issues. It's getting extremely annoying. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

OS: Windows 7
DNS: Google
Devices Connected: 4

**I've tried:**

- Resetting router to default settings
- Using ISP DNS
- Reinstalled network drivers
- Virtual machine
- Changed router signal
- No ports open
- Disabled firewall on router/PC

Comment: I would start with `ipconfig release`, `ipconfig flushdns`, and `ipconfig renew` to request a new address. Is this machine configured for a static IP? If for some reason your router is having trouble choosing an IP to assign to this machine, you may want to set the NIC to have a static IP. What make/model is your router?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it happened again when i was idle. My router is a Netgear VMDG480 and i've already performed those commands many times it doesn't do anything. Although just now when it was 'resolving host' I performed iprelease and it caused chrome to crash and error out 'Exception Breakpoint'. Again not the first time its happened. I have tried Firefox when I experienced this issue and that will not connect either.

Comment: Have you checked the power/sleep settings on your NIC/WNIC? In the device manager, right click on your NIC and go to Properties. Check each setting and make sure there aren't any weird power settings putting the device to sleep. Is your connection only dropping after having been idle for some time? I'd leave a `ping google.com -t` on to see if frequently making requests over the network holds your connection.

Comment: Sorry the late reply wasn't able to connect for so long. 

-t does indeed drop the connection. On my Realtek NIC Powersaving is set to disabled. Power Management has 'Allow pc to turn off device to save power' (just disabled, didnt do anything). The connection doesnt just drop when I'm idle it happens at random times when i'm browsing (Takes a while to connect again) Come to the conclusion releasing the IP crashes chrome also. When i renew it appears assign an IP instantly when infact it does not, just resolves host. Takes forever to identify after enable/disable.

Comment: Also, make sure you do not have physical connection problem: check your cable, RJ-45 on both ends of the cable.

Comment: Have you tried directly connecting your computer to the modem? Does that work?